# Passing a variable through a segue? Xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

So I am creating an alarm clock. One view controller is a table view. The other view controller consists of a UIDatePicker with a submit button. The goal is that when the user clicks the submit button, it saves the date on the date picker. As well as saving the date, it is a segue to the table view controller. I am trying to display the time saved as the label in the cell.

1. This is my code for the DatePicker view controller. I defined the variable outside of the function. Then when they click submit it should update the value. However it does not update it when it passes through the segue.

   ```
    var myDate = "1:39 PM"




   @IBAction func submitDate(_ sender: AnyObject) {

      myDate = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: dateOutlet.date, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.none, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short)


   }


   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       if segue.identifier == "save" {

           let toViewController = segue.destination as! TableViewController

           toViewController.myDate = myDate



       }
   }
   ```
2. This is my code for the table view controller. When i click submit, it does not show the label as the time chosen in the DatePicker. It shows "1: 39 PM." Which was what I initially defined it as.

   ```
   var myDate = "0"


   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



       let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell


       cell.textLabel?.text = myDate

       return cell



   }
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Don't bother trying to declare `myDate` in your source view controller unless you are going to use it later.

Also, if you didn't have any code in your `submitDate` function to present your target view controller, you probably don't need it as your `'save'` segue you set takes care of that automatically.

**In source view controller**

```
@IBAction func submitDate(_ sender: AnyObject) {

   //don't need anything here - remove this function unless doing anything else


}


   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "save" {
        if let toViewController = segue.destination as? TableViewController {
            toViewController.myDate = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: dateOutlet.date, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.none, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.short)
        }
    }
}
```

**In target view controller**

```
var myDate: String!


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell


    cell.textLabel?.text = myDate

    return cell



}
```