# How to pass data from map annotation to another VC

Tags: ios, mapkit, swift4

this is my first question so sorry for mistakes. I found some answers but nothing work in my code. 
First of all

I made segue and add identifier.

this is in my MainMapViewController:

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        guard let annotation = mapView.selectedAnnotations.first else {return}
        annotationPlace = annotation as? Place
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
    }

    func showPlaceDetail(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        let viewController = segue.destination as? PlaceDetailTableViewController
        viewController?.selectedPlace = annotationPlace
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            showPlaceDetail(segue: segue)
        }
    }
```

Here is my PlaceDetailTableViewController:

```
   import UIKit

class PlaceDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var selectedPlace:Place?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dump(selectedPlace as Any)
        print(selectedPlace?.title)
    }
}
```

*In my opinion it is something different like normal passing data between VC's because i have to make segue from annotation button*

Comment: Which segeu method u r using ? Push or Model ?

Comment: I'm using push. I'm beginner so for now i don't see a diference

Comment: `dump(selectedPlace as Any)` why this line is required ?

Comment: in my opinion it should print the passed data and it is not required. I took it from book

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a variable through a segue? Xcode 8 Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454562/passing-a-variable-through-a-segue-xcode-8-swift-3)

Comment: Can you please show your storyboard and the identifier for the segue. e.g. http://i.stack.imgur.com/GFsqF.png

Comment: https://ibb.co/iM5qKH here is my storyboard

Comment: Ummm... Your storyboard is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try This way:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let toViewController = segue.destination as? PlaceDetailTableViewController {
           toViewController.selectedPlace = annotationPlace
        }
    }
}
```

remove `showPlaceDetail` function. and print `selectedPlace.title` before **dumb** method.

Comment: i tried now and earlier before that question. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe i make mistake some were else.

Comment: sorry but it should be working. what error are you getting?@KrzysztofLema